# GWT security one more time

Tags: gwt, architecture, security

I'm going to develop site accessible to anonymous and registered users. Planed security schema is similar to let's say YouTube and most of others "web 2.0" sites. Logged user will get access to more functions, more data etc. What is best approach to implement that?
I'm thinking about create simple service returning random session code to client, and adding session object to singleton application object. When user provide credential, I'll change parameter "logged" in his session object. Session token will be passed as one of parameters in every single request, and services will change their behavior if user is registered or not (i.e. there will be returned only "public" data, or restricted content only)
Is it good approach, or should I use something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherently different about GWT security, it is the same with JSP,PHP, ASP, ROR, etc..., that is web application security.

There is already a session mechanism on the server side, that generates secure random session cookies, use it. As a bonus, it handles session expiration and other things you would have to handle if you rolled your own.

1. You cannot trust ANYTHING the client sends you, so if you send the username or some kind of token from the client to the server (other than the user logging in), you are doing it wrong.
2. If your information has any value, force SSL on all connections.

Your implementation of the server calls should check the server session for the current user info, and determine if the user is authorized to perform the action. Again, your RPC information should not include any information about the user making the call, other than the session cookie that is sent automatically with the request headers. Anything you store, such as whether the user is logged in, should be in the server side session.

Of course, you need to do something on the client to present logged in and anonymous users with the proper user interface. But that is **not** security, only work to present a consistent interface. All the security is on the server side.